# How can I force UNIX sed command to act in lazy mode?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to use the UNIX command to remove hundreds of PHP `eval(base64_decode(...));` statements inserted by a hacker into a client's website.  When I tried the folowing:

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs sed -i .bck 's/eval(base64_decode(.*));//g'
```

the results were great, except that sometimes the `eval` code was followed by some legitimate code that ends with `"));"`, and that would get removed as well.

How can I force sed to stop at the first (smallest) match to the pattern I give it?

Comment: What do you mean by "`eval` code was followed by some legitimate code that ends with `"));"`?

Answer (score 4):

Tell it to stop at the first instance of the character.

```
...([^)]*);...
```